# EEPROM ESP8266 - Inverted Question Mark

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, eeprom

Im stuck here. I am trying to SAVE/LOAD board configuration to EEPROM in ESP8266 using my modified version of [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/DNSServer/examples/CaptivePortalAdvanced/credentials.ino) example.

Here is my actual code:

```
char ssid[32] = "";
char password[32] = "";
char device_type[1] = "";
char device_name[32] = "";

/** Load WLAN credentials from EEPROM */
void loadBoardConfig()
{

  EEPROM.begin(512);

  int addr = 0;
  EEPROM.get(0, ssid);

  addr += sizeof(ssid);
  EEPROM.get(addr, password);

  addr += sizeof(password);
  EEPROM.get(addr, device_type);

  addr += sizeof(device_type);
  EEPROM.get(addr, device_name);

  addr += sizeof(device_name);

  char ok[2 + 1];
  EEPROM.get(addr, ok);

  EEPROM.end();

  if (String(ok) != String("OK"))
  {
    ssid[0] = 0;
    password[0] = 0;
    device_type[0] = 0;
    device_name[0] = 0;
  }
}

/** Store Board Config to EEPROM */
void saveBoardConfig()
{

  EEPROM.begin(512);

  int addr = 0;
  EEPROM.put(addr, ssid);

  addr += sizeof(ssid);
  EEPROM.put(addr, password);

  addr += sizeof(password);
  EEPROM.put(addr, device_type);

  addr += sizeof(device_type);
  EEPROM.put(addr, device_name);

  addr += sizeof(device_name);
  char ok[2 + 1] = "OK";
  EEPROM.put(addr, ok);

  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
}
```

I realized there it wasnt connecting properly to WiFi so i added this piece of code to test:

```
Serial.print("EEPROM CONFIG: [{ SSID: ");
Serial.printf("%c",ssid);
Serial.print(" },\n{ Password: ");
Serial.print(password);
Serial.print(" },\n{ Device Type: ");
Serial.print(device_type);
Serial.print(" },\n{ Device Name: ");
Serial.print(device_name);
Serial.println(" }]");
Serial.print("STATUS: ");
Serial.println(ok);
```

This is the result im getting in Serial Monitor:

```
EEPROM CONFIG: [{ SSID: ⸮ },
{ Password: ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ },
{ Device Type: ⸮ },
{ Device Name: ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ }]
STATUS: ⸮⸮⸮?x⸮ @⸮⸮⸮?
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Looks like the pattern [`2e`](https://unicode-table.com/en/2E2E/) is stored in your eeprom?

Comment: Why does your branch say this:  if (String(ok) != String("OK"))         Instead of this:  if (String("ok") != String("OK"))

Comment: @hellow I double checked. The data is correct upon saving.

Comment: @Drt  ok as a variable that is stored after all others. If everything was ok when read it should have "OK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. The code is OK, but ESP8266 does not have an actual EEPROM. Instead it is emulated an saved in the flash and I had my settings to erase all flash contents. I just switched to "Only Sketch" and it worked!
Thanks!